# Where to find x64 version of Office Interop assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-office

I am trying to run [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3582/Word-Control-for-NET?fid=14182&df=10000&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&spc=Relaxed&fr=76#xx0xx) in my VisualStudio 2010.
it build and run fine on my 64 bit Machine.

NOTE:I have to change build Platform of my project to x86.

my problem is when I try to run compiled assembly (after moving Debug Folder to another 64 Bit machine) I couldn't run my project. my exe breaks down when I open it.

as per my understanding problem is because of three DLL used in project are 32 BIT and Machine is 64Bit.

NOTE: below is three DLL

```
Interop.Office.dll

Interop.VBIDE.dll

Interop.Word.dll
```

I googled much but couldn't found any solution?
one solution comes in my mind is manage to get 64BIT version of above DLL for that also I have googled much but couldn't get anything.
could you please help me to find solution for this problem? or is there any way to found 64BIT version of above DLL?

Comment: Did you find where to download those ? I cant find them either....

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use 32 bit dlls, probably you cannot run your application, compiled on 64 bits.

So you need to compile all your project (as you did for debug) in the 32 bits mode before release to another pc.

You can ensure your dlls compiled right (32 bits only), using Microsoft [CorFlags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) utility.

If you'll find that dll is not 32bits, you can also try to change it with same utility (**/32BITS** falg).

Answer (score 1):

More information:

The default version of Office is 32 bit version.

To get 64 bit versions of the assemblies you need to specifically install 64 bit office (see [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/support/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA102840825.aspx).)
The 64 bit version of Office should be able to use your 32 bit program (using WoW) 
but it's best if you create (and test) two versions of it: one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit.

Unfortunately this means two development environments as the 32 bit Office [cannot be installed along side the 64 bit one.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/support/why-cant-i-install-both-the-32-bit-and-64-bit-versions-of-office-2013-HA103523746.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Are you positive that the office interOps are the problem?

What is the error message you are receiving? You have stated that you are compiling with x86 platform build mode. Therefore your dlls will run as 32 bit processes even on the other 64bit machine and will therefore call the 32bit office dlls.

If you had of compiled as AnyCPU then I could see how the error you are getting relates to office dll bitness, because your application would start in 64bit (on a 64bit machine) and then attempt to call into the 32bit office dlls.

But I fail to understand how you're finding that the 32bit dlls are the problem on any 32 or 64bit machine since you are compiling to 32bit (x86). So your assembly manifest is telling the JIT compiler, "hey Im a 32bit process".

Remember, ngen aside, the bitness of your code isn't determined till it's run. Post compilation the code is just IL waiting to be compiled and it's the same IL regardless of whether you had a build platform of x86 or x64 or AnyCPU.

When it's run the runtime looks at the manifest and compiles it to the platform of choice... which in this case is x86... from what you have said.

So the problem is not that:

> three DLL used in project are 32 BIT and Machine is 64Bit.

32bit dlls are used all over the place on 64bit machines. Visual Studio itself is a 32bit application and runs just fine on 64bit machine. The problem (IMHO) is either

1. Not the office dlls at all but something else... Office is installed on the other machine I assume.
2. You've accidentally changed the target platform of the last build you did before deploying to something other than x86.